# How to check whether a target has been added or not?

Tags: cmake

Assume I have a cmake macro that adds target (library or executable) based on some conditions

```
macro (conditionally_add target_name target_src condition)
  if (condition)
    add_library (target_name target_src)
  endif ()
endmacro()
```

My question is, after calling this function

```
conditionally_add (mylib mysrc.cc ${some_condition})
```

How can I check whether the library has been added? More specifically, I'd like to do something below

```
if (my_lib_is_added)    # HOW TO DO THIS?
  # Do something.
endif ()
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use the `TARGET` clause of the `if` command:

```
conditionally_add (mylib mysrc.cc ${some_condition})
if (TARGET mylib)
  # Do something when target found
endif()
```