# CMake: check that library as static target exists at configuration stage

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

Let's imagine that I declare a static library in a separate CMakeLists.txt like that:

```
add_library(foo STATIC foo.cpp)
```

And in the main CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(foolibfolder)

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)
```

The issue is that if I rename `foo` in its CMakeLists.txt and forget to do renaming in main CMakeLists.txt then it would be known only at linking stage of `bar` executable that there is no library `-llibfoo`. Is there a way to check existance of `bar`'s dependancy  at configuration stage?

Comment: As far as I know, CMake doesn't have a "switch" which requires arguments for `target_link_libraries` to be only targets. If you want to check this manually, see that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241734/3440745) to the related question. Alternatively, you may create `ALIAS` library (named, e.g. `foo::foo`) and use it in the `target_link_libraries` call: with [CMP0028](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/policy/CMP0028.html) policy CMake will check that every "namespaced" name corresponds to the real target.